# Segregating Offline Server and Internet Connection in one pc

Tags: webserver, hardening

**What I want to do:**

Setup a PC with two routers. One router is directly connected to the internet, the other is connected to an offline workspace server. My client will be connected to both via a physical ethernet switchbox. The purpose of the server is to act as a database/webserver for various research. I would like to have the capacity to securely store my data away from my regularly used computer, but still have on-the-fly access when its needed.

**My question:**

What potential threats could be posed (by a **remote attacker**) to the offline server if the connecting device is temporarily not connected to an outside connection?

**Possible Threats I see:**

1. Any persistant spyware on the system would still be able to access anything recorded on my client machine and possibly see cached information about the server connection.

**Other considerations:**

1. Server and client will not have wifi/bluetooth hardware installed, only cable ethernet.

Answer (score 2):

Any malware you get on your workstation can then do whatever you could do to the server, including copying any files, saving credentials, etc.  Additionally, while you're connected to the internet, the malware could essentially proxy attacker traffic to the server.

The setup you've described is arguably more secure if your client is not compromised.  Your server is essentially segregated from the internet, so reduces its vulnerability to attack.  Of course, you're also adding complexity: how will you install new software, patches, etc.?  You'll need some way to get that traffic to/from the internet.

Comment: In reference to proxying the attack traffic to the server via the workstation. That would be impossible (unless there was some sort of prebuilt load that shot out without needing to maintain a connection) because through a physical ethernet switchbox, there would be no way to pass traffic, because it would only be connected to one of the networks at a time.

Comment: http://goo.gl/sm1y50 < This is what I'm thinking of using. It physically disconnects and switches the circuit between the networks, as if unplugging each.

Comment: As for you're other comments, you're absolutely right. I would need to connect it to the internet at times for updating (or via USB/CD). But if I can limit it's exposure and not form a pattern when updating, I still think this could increase security.

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why you want to do this? This sort of physical segregation is (if done correctly) a high level of security, and normally only used for ultra-critical systems - military, intelligence, etc. It is rarely used in commercial environments, including banking. In your environment, you may do better to forget all about segregating, simply follow good security practice (firewalls, AV, etc.) and live with the residual risk.

If you are going to do this, as David says, the weak point is malware on your PC. And that is a major weak point - because malware is the number one threat to your security, even if you follow good security practice.

So the only way to do this properly is to segregate the PC as well. Perhaps by having two PCs and a KVM switch, or by having two virtual machines on your PC. The latter is slightly less secure than physical separation, due to the risk to guest-vs-host attacks, but a substantial improvement on a single PC.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons I want to do this. One reason is that I have a vested interest in computer security, so learning new ways of securing them (an possibly violating that security) is something I'm interested in. The second reason is that I am working with potentially sensitive data that I prefer stay confidential. I also tend to deal with people who are... Shall we say, into the same interests as myself.

Comment: In reference to your suggestions, this is similar to what I have implemented now: Two systems on a LAN using a KVM, one with encrypted virtual servers installed that are up when needed an down when not. However this to me seems far more vulnerable than my above suggestion. Especially in the case of my system potentially becoming infected with malware.

Comment: @P0LYmath - Ok, if you have a vested interest and are prepared for a bit of effort and inconvenience, you can do this. Regarding your second comment, I can't really make an assessment based on this limited information. If you like, we could setup a chat room and discuss in more detail.

Comment: I am certainly interested and appreciate your offer. However, I'm still new and have yet to receive the required 20 points needed to chat.